# Is it possible to transpile generators with Babel?

Tags: gulp, ecmascript-6, generator, babeljs

I have simple code of generator:

```
function *foo(){}
```

I have a gulp babel which looks like this:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('default', () => {
    return gulp.src('src/app.js')
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

When u run `gulp` it finished nice but when i go to html page where I'm adding my dist/app.js file i see an error in console:

```
ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
```

I've read about it but its recommended to add a plugin which handle generators and when I'm doing that I have an error that require is not defined... Can someone please tell how to make babel working well with generators step-by-step?

Answer (score 3):

You need to include [babel-polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) in your build

> Babel includes a polyfill that includes a custom **[regenerator runtime](https://github.com/facebook/regenerator/blob/master/runtime.js)** and core-js.

Install **babel-polyfill**

```
$ npm install --save-dev babel-polyfill
```

Make sure you add this to **src/app.js**

```
// src/app.js
import "babel-polyfill";
```